# How to pass an object to the html attribute for buefy component

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I'm looking at the docs for datetimepicker for Buefy.

I would like to pass a time formatter for the timepicker in datetimepicker.
In the doc it says  **"timepicker,  Any timepicker props,   Object  "**
[buefy api](https://buefy.org/documentation/datetimepicker/)
to pass an object. But I get errors if I try this.

```html
<b-datetimepicker
     placeholder="Click to select..."
     v-model="datepicker_value"
     :datetime-formatter="formatter"
     :timepicker={'time-formatter'="t_formatter"}
    >
</b-datetimepicker>
```

I don't know how to pass the formatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you're passing isn't valid javascript. Also, the expected property for the `time-formatter` parameter isn't a string representing a function, but an actual function. Let's fix it:

First, let's fix our javascript error and the callback function parameter:

```
:timepicker="{'time-formatter': t_formatter}"
```

Now let's make sure we declare that function within our vue template:

```
t_formatter (time) {
  return Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { timezone: "UTC" }).format(time)
}
```

Now you should be able to modify the time appropriately.

Comment: thank you, but I see no effect : https://codepen.io/freddy9877/pen/xxRzVma?editors=1011

Comment: My purpose is to show UTC  datetime, but it reverts to Local timezone

Comment: There was a typo. timezome: "UTC", instead of timezone: "UTC". I edited it.

Comment: ty for the correction, but still no change in the result